# ERR:Unknown column in where clause when query with struct

Tags: go-gorm

```
db.Table("test").Where(&Query{Name:"test"}).Find(&infos)
```

When I execute this statement, the SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`  WHERE (`queries`.`name` = 'test')
```

And the error：

```
Error 1054: Unknown column 'queries.name' in 'where clause'
```

It uses the name of my struct instead of the table name

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the latest version of Gorm v2? I cannot reproduce what you see: the code you wrote produces

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `test`.`name` = "test"
```

In any case, if you don't use the `Query` struct, but instead write out the condition it should work:

```golang
db.Table("test").Where("name = ?", "test").Find(&infos)
```

Or you can use a map:

```golang
db.Table("test").Where(map[string]interface{}{"Name": "test"}).Find(&infos)
```